# The same google tag triggers for different tags and websites

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a one Google tags container for 2 websites: web1 and web2.
I have one simple trigger created -> "Some Link Clicks" -> click class to check if someone clicks email addresses.

This trigger is used by 2 tags created for these 2 websites. Each tag is connected to different Analytics property (each website has its own analytics).

All seems to work except it seems that each click is counted on both websites, no matter on which website it was clicked. So when someone is clicking email in web1 I see it also in analytics stats on web2, even if these are 2 different tags and analytics IDs.

Tags are both set to

- Type: event,
- Category: "contact" ,
- Action: "email-click",

And the same goals of event type are added in analytics with the same names.

- Is it how tags should work?
- Should I create 2 different "link Clicks" triggers for each tag, even if they will have the same settings, and assign them separately to each tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to mitigate this. You made a mistake of making the same tags on the same triggers and expecting them firing differently.

The **junior** thing you could do is - yes, edit your triggers and add a condition there that would check the hostname on that trigger. So not all link clicks, but the ones where hostname is what you expect.

The **mid** thing to do is to use blocking triggers that block the trigger from firing whenever the hostname is not what you expect it to be.

The **senior** (and the proper way of doing it) is to delete all duplicate tags that you have there. Then to change the hardcoded tracking ids into a simple look-up table that would return a proper tracking id depending on the hostname of where that tag has fired.

Choose what feels more appropriate and you should be all set.